# How to convert Microsoft Excel xlsx file to mysql database .sql file

Tags: mysql, database, excel

I'm using Microsoft Excel as a database since 2000 but I would like to update application as a web based platform. So I need to convert my `.xlsx` database to a `.SQL` file to access in a new program.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. .xlsx holds data, .sql is a way to access data. What do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your database as .CSV(comma-separated-values) file in Excel and use SQL Server Managament Studio to import it, after that you can do what you want and export your database as SQL File.